# How do I pass arguments inside a remote command using sshpass and ssh

Tags: parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, sshpass

I am running the following code and unable to pass an argument in the command that I am executing on a remote Netapp cluster. Any insight will help

read -p  "`echo $'\n'`Enter the name for this cluster:" cluster

sshpass -p $pswd ssh $username@$hostname 'aggr show; aggr create -aggregate agg1_'$cluster' -disklist 1.0.0,1.0.1,1.0.2,1.0.3,1.0.4,1.0.5,1.0.6,1.0.7 -simulate true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tried below syntax to append the variable into the command that I need to execute..

sshpass -p $pswd ssh $username@$hostname "aggr show; aggr create -aggregate agg1_**"$cluster"** -disklist 1.0.0,1.0.1,1.0.2,1.0.3,1.0.4,1.0.5,1.0.6,1.0.7 -simulate true"